# What are the different ways to set the length scales of the kernel to be positive and be in the interval range

Tags: python, regression, gaussian-process, gpytorch

I'm using the following kernel for my Gaussian process regression with optimizer as Adam. But when i print the model optimized parameters the length scales are not in the interval range i provided.

```
class GPR(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super(GPR, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
        lengthscale_constraint1 = Interval(lower_bound=1,upper_bound=10)
        covar_module1 = gpytorch.kernels.Scalekernel(gpytorch.kernels.RQKernel(ard_nums_dims=train_x.shape[1],lengthscale_constraint= lengthsclae_constraint1))
        covar_module1.outputscale = 3.542
        covar_module1.raw_outputscale.requires_grad=False
        raw_alpha = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1e-20]))
        covar_module1.base_kernel.register_parameter("raw_alpha", raw_alpha)
        covar_module1.base_kernel.raw_alpha.requires_grad = False
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.LinearKernel() + covar_module1
```

**Actual Output**

length scales are negative and not in the range.
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZ2G.png)

**Expected output**

The length scales to be in the range of 1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that GPyTorch has raw and true parameters, where the true parameters are inverse transformed to the raw parameters, see the [docs](https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/stable/examples/00_Basic_Usage/Hyperparameters.html#Raw-vs-Actual-Parameters). This is how constraints are applied to the true parameters.

The raw parameters have the prefix "raw" (eg. "raw_lengthscale"). For example, [here](https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch/blob/d19f52e07e2cc5dd69d35457d0792072adf37574/gpytorch/kernels/kernel.py#L223) is how the lengthscale setter is defined in the `Kernel` class:

```
    def _set_lengthscale(self, value: Tensor):
        # Used by the lengthscale_prior
        if not self.has_lengthscale:
            raise RuntimeError("Kernel has no lengthscale.")

        if not torch.is_tensor(value):
            value = torch.as_tensor(value).to(self.raw_lengthscale)

        self.initialize(raw_lengthscale=self.raw_lengthscale_constraint.inverse_transform(value))
```

As you can see the true parameter `value` (the true lengthscale) is inverse transformed to the corresponding `raw_lengthscale`.

If you are priting out parameters by doing

```
for param_name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(param_name, param)
```

this will print the raw_parameters. You will then need to apply the appropriate transform to the raw parameters. To do this you can use

```
for name, param, constraint in model.named_parameters_and_constraints():

    print(name, constraint.transform(param))
```

Note that `name` will still contain `raw` even if the true value of the parameter is being printed.